# FastMember column order preservation

Tags: c#, reflection, fastmember

When using TypeAccessor.Create FastMember always seems to return a list of the columns in alphabetic sorted order. Is it possible to tell it to preserve the ordering of the columns in the class?

for example:

```
var testClass = new { B = "1", A = "2" };
```

will return column A then B from GetMembers, I'd like to get it to preserve the ordering of B then A if possible.

Comment: Curious, why exactly you need that?

Comment: kind of like the bulk insert, but I'd like to be able to throw data into other data stores too, some of which might care about ordering. @Evk

Comment: Without heavy reflection I think you cannot do that. Deep inside FastMember library author orders properties by name and seems there is no way around it. If that is a requirement, you can either ask author to add such functionality, or not use this library at all.

Comment: Other option would be to get properties with reflection once, yourself, and then reoder result of GetMembers manually.

Comment: yeah @evk that might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Evk is right and it can't really be done via the standard APIs. In the interest of completeness I'll leave this as the answer.

Comment: I ran into the same problem: passing a dt into a user defined table type for a stored procedure kept failing due to columns being ordered alphabetically but FastMember. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

I created a [fork](https://github.com/dyatchenko/fast-member) of this project with column order option and added a [PR](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/pull/73) to the original repository. `OrdinalAttribute` was added to specify columns order.

The ordinal attribute can be used as shown below:

```cs
        public class ObjectReaderWithDefinedColumnsOrderType
        {
            [Ordinal(1)]
            public byte C { get; set; }
            [Ordinal(0)]
            public int? D { get; set; }
        }
```

- `IDataReader` object returned in `ObjectReader.Create()` will have columns order according to the defined attributes.
- If the attribute is not defined in the source class then alphabetical order is used.
- If two fields have the same Ordinal value then then alphabetical order is used.
- If the attribute is defined only for some properties then the columns are sorted by the ordinal values and then in alphabetical order (properties with no attributes are considered as `-1` ordinal).

You can use my for right away or wait until the PR is merged with the original repository.

Comment: Has your pull request been processed yet?

Comment: @Martin, yes, it has been merged to master.

Comment: @dyatchenko what the latest with this? Does it work?

Comment: @EmilijaVilijaTrečiokaitė yes, it works and merged. Please use latest version of the component.